# Error Term in ANOVA in R

Tags: anova, dataset

I am trying around with a few different ways trying to understand about the Error term specified in aov().
I am using the dataset Plasma from package gamlss.data, with 5 columns like below

`head(df)
  age sex smokstat      bmi cholesterol
1  64   2        2 21.48380       170.3
2  76   2        1 23.87631        75.8
3  38   2        2 20.01080       257.9
4  40   2        2 25.14062       332.6
5  72   2        1 20.98504       170.8
6  40   2        2 27.52136       154.6`

Firstly, I take that aov fits a model as suggested from this
[link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247582/repeated-measures-anova-in-r-errorsubject-vs-errorsubject-day)

At first I fit the model

```
md <- aov(cholesterol~smokstat+Error(sex/smokstat), df)
```

when I call coef(md) I get the results:

```
    (Intercept) :
(Intercept) 
   242.4606 

sex :
smokstat2 
  539.678 

sex:smokstat :
smokstat2 smokstat3 
 11.67864  36.50799 

Within :
numeric(0)
```

I understand that the intercept is the global mean, and the smokstat2 and smokstat3 in sex:smokstat is the amount addded if you choose smokstat 2 over smokstat3 over smokstat1.

However, I don't understand what the block "sex: smokstat2 539.678" is? How I should interpret it? Why it is there instead of the "Residual" from between- subject variance?

Please add more information if I haven't made anything clear as I'm still confused by this rn. Thanks in advance. I appreciate your help.

Comment: can you make sex a factor and run it again? df$sex = factor(df$sex)

Comment: sex is already a factor with 2 levels @StupidWolf